# next() doesn't select an element

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
  <div>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li class="fifth-item">list item 5</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
  </div>
```

and this jQuery code:

```
$( "li.third-item" ).next(".fifth-item").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

which is supposed to paint this `<li>` item to red:

```
<li class="fifth-item">list item 5</li>
```

I've tried all sorts of things, but can't figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** selects siblings immediately after the element, in your case `.fifth-item` is not immediately after. So you need to use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/)** and **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)**

1. **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/)** - get all siblings next to the element
2. **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)** - to get the first element from the collection

```js
$("li.third-item").nextAll(".fifth-item").first().css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li class="fifth-item">list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No need of using `first()`. OP might want to select all the elements(_from code in question_) or there is only one element with that class.

Comment: @Tushar : in case if he want to select first element, since `next()` will only select one element

Comment: I'm not sure if next() selects siblings immediately after the element. My question was specifically related to the arguments in next() and my confusion around all of this. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841748/confused-how-next-arguments-work

Comment: @daremkd __Description:__ `Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.` ( _Taken for : https://api.jquery.com/next/_ )